# How to remove the stackoverflow extension from VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I don't remember where I installed this extension but it's pretty annoying me because it shows the reputation instead of concentrating in my inbox and recent activity.

Anyway I looked around trying to get rid of it and couldn't find it in the extensions, does anyone knows where it can be found and uninstalled?

Here's the extension, it's embedded on VS top title-bar.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this go on meta or stackapps instead? This is about usage, not actual development.

Comment: Remove it from context menu on Visual Studio title bar http://vscommands.squaredinfinity.com/Media/VSCommands/BlogPost//blog/stackoverflow-enable.png

Comment: @TeoKlestrupRöijezon sorry and thanks for closing, I thought it's related to the usage of VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a functionnality added by the VSCommand extension.

You can remove it from context menu on Visual Studio titlebar:

[image]

Comment: Hey Jarek! Thanks for the wonderful extension, VSCommands is a part of VS to me, can't go one step without it! Anyway per the SO extension, as I said, I think it would be better if the extension shows inbox/recent rather than rep, I'd love to see the inbox drop down in VS (preferably of all StackExchange), here's what I mean: http://goo.gl/VQm49P. Thanks <3

Comment: That's a very good idea! I'll have to update StackOverflow integration anyway because 1.1 version of so api (used currently) will be retired soon. From what I've seen so api 2.1 should allow access to inbox contents.